# json_encode truncating when reading from on database but not another

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I have a json_encode statement in my site running php, that when I run it on a MariaDB server on my local machine it loads.  I then did a mysqldump of the data and put it on a MariaDB server hosted on AWS RDS, and I get console errors saying missing the end of JSON, etc.

After much digging we figured out the json encode was crapping out and not returning fully json formatted data.

I checked PHP max memory is 512mb which should be plenty

I have checked that the default character sets are both utf8mb4 on both databases.  I've checked the `show create database.tablename` and they are all set to utf8mb4 and the mysqldump file also reflects that.

When I run `show table status` all the tables have 'utf8_unicode_ci' in the Collation field.

When I take another known working webserver and point it to the same database I get the same issue.  So to me it seems DB related, not php. Because again, when I put the same data on my local server, it loads.

I'm clearly missing a setting on the AWS RDS database. Been banging my head all day, but cannot figure out it.  I'm sorry I don't have much more. I'm at a loss.

Comment: Have you checked that the data is complete **before** you `json_encode()` it?

Comment: Good question, so we figured out that on the local db, all the data loads (612 entries), but on the AWS rds, it dies after like 300 entries or so.

Comment: Either it's https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.KnownIssuesAndLimitations.html or another limitation: if you expect tons of bytes as results then prepare for running out of space somewhere. How about issuing multiple queries instead of one?

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES;` (on RWS).  There are a couple of settings that might cause a problem.  Do you know how big the offending JSON is?  On the source machine:  `SELECT MAX(LENGTH(my_json_col)) FROM my_table;`